# Script to remove .vb files from a directory

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to remove .vb code files when there are corresponding .cs files in a certain directory structure.  But I felt like there were some extra statements that I had to put in there that didn't feel natural.  Is there a better way to do this check and then action?

Specifically, having to do the `foreach` at the end didn't seem right to me.  I also didn't know if there was a more PowerShell-y way to do the change extension and test-path.

```
ls . -include *.vb -recurse 
    | ? { $cs = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, ".cs"); Test-Path $cs } 
    | % { rm $_ -force }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [combine expression vs. command mode](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/) in PowerShell, process only files (`!$_.PSIsContainer`) and use regex instead of `ChangeExtension`:

```
gci -include *.vb -Recurse |
    ? { (!$_.PSIsContainer) -and (Test-Path ($_.FullName -replace "\.vb$", ".cs") } |
    % { rm $_ -force }
```

Comment: That's a big one, I couldn't figure out why I needed the temporary `$cs` variable; just wrapping it in parens fixes it from encountering "parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'" (and makes sense now that I look though that article and see the fix).  Thanks!

Comment: And it looks like I don't need to specify `$_.FullPath`, but can just use `$_` (with either the `ChangeExtension` or `-replace` method)

Comment: It doesn't look like `gci *.vb -recurse` actually recurses. I think I have to specify current directory as the path, then `*.vb` as the filter for recursing to work correctly.

Comment: you are right: `gci -include *.vb -Recurse` — works much _better_

Comment: Actually, removing `FullPath` breaks it once you get into the deeper folders, since you're only getting the name by default, not the full path.